# Only execute function once per day with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm just looking for some general direction as to how to solve this problem.

I have an Ionic app (AngularJS) and I want to ensure that I execute a section of code only once per day.

Without a horrid method of setting a variable once per day and checking against that I can't think of a good pattern for it.

Any suggestions appreciated. My google searches haven't turned up much.

Comment: You can think of `$interval` with `interval of day`..

Comment: $interval should work but does your app run that long ? If the app is closed, interval timer would start again.

Comment: store date in a varialble, when user opens the app again, check the date with stored date if the difference is '>1' execute the code and reset the date